# Nativescript chart plugin

Tags: plugins, graph, charts, nativescript

It there any free to use plugin or javascript library compatible with Nativescript so I could make at least bar charts vertically or horizontally. There seems to be lack of information around this criteria. I'm not going to use telerik pro stuff.

Comment: Telerik has a chart component, but it is only for the pro version: http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui#chart

Comment: --> "I'm not going to use telerik pro stuff."

Comment: To add something to my question. If there's no any plugins available could someone tell me how to use third party libraries like chart.js in nativescript.

Comment: I would also add that you should check the http://plugins.nativescript.rocks site for any plugins that exist.

Comment: Looks like same listing as found from npm. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Update March 1, 2018**

As Shaunti mentions in a comment, the [chart library from NativeScript](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui#chart) is now free of charge.

**Using native third party libraries:**

One of  the main benefits of NativeScript is that you're free to use any native third party libraries you want (iOS Cocoapods or Android libraries). For example, you can use [Charts Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/charts) or [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

There's several hundred free-to-use/open source chart libraries available out there. It's just a matter of finding one which suits your needs.

Here's a blog post about using native third party libraries in NativeScript: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/using-native-libraries-in-nativescript/

**About chart.js etc**

Chart.js etc are **HTML** solutions. They produce HTML. Nativescript is not a HTML based solution (such as PhoneGap etc). Nativescript produces actual native code. Here's a short video explaining the difference between a native solution and a web based solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R98cdsq1qxA

Therefor you will *not* be able to use web based technologies.

**Final words**

I suggest that you rethink not wanting to use the readymade Telerik components. If you don't have experience with working with Cocoapods/Android libraries and don't have that much experience with NativeScript itself it will most probably cost you quite a bit of time to get things up and running.

Compare your time cost with the $199 cost for the [UI for NativeScript components](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript-ui#chart)

Comment: Whoah, Emil Oberg! I have watched your tutorial videos and articles a lot! Thanks for your very informative post.

Comment: Actually I would disagree with the statement about using a web based technology in NativeScript.  You CAN use one; but you have to basically drop it into a web control and then you have to transport the data into the browser for it to render.   It can be done, but it would be slower and not nearly as good of a solution as using a native solution.

I totally agree with Emil on the question; what is your time worth?

Comment: @Nathanael is totally right. I've even walked that route myself. My original answer was a simplification trying to show the difference between web based technologies and and native ones.

Comment: FYI the components are now free and I still stopped using them!

Comment: In yours experiences what choise do you recommend?